# When merging dataframes in python, what should i do if there is a list element in the frame? (unhashable type: 'list')

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I need to merge in row.

Such frames look like below.

[First DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8iWt.png)

[Second DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Co4.png)

It outputs ( unhashable type: 'list' ) error.

I think there is a problem with adding the list elements (ex) [0, 0, 0, 1] or [0, 0, 1, 0].

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I think your issue is. Im using the two dataframes below as an example:

```
DF 1 :
       | A      B
    ---+----------------------------
    0  | 'A'    ['A', 'B']
    1  | 'B'    ['B', 'D']
    2  | 'C'    ['D', 'E', 'F']

DF 2 :
   | C      D
---+----------------------------
0  | 'A'    'X'
1  | 'B'    'Y'
2  | 'C'    'Z'
```

First you want to deal with unnesting. Then follow that with a merge:

```
df3=unnesting(df1,['B'])
df3.merge(df2,left_on='B',right_on='C',how='inner').drop('B',1).merge(df1)
Out[15]: 
   A  C  D       B
0  A  A  X  [A, B]
1  A  B  Y  [A, B]
2  B  B  Y  [B, D]
```

Here is the function for unnesting:

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
```